# Work done on box

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy, work, velocity

[image]

I am having a hard time grasping this. W = Fd = mad, and given v vs t graph, the area under the curve will give us d. When the velocity graph draws a horizontal line, a=0. Thus I thought that A = C will have W = 0, but D would also have W = 0 because the positive and negative areas under the curves cancel out to give d=0.

However, the answer states otherwise (blue ink). Could someone help me understand why please? Thank you!

Comment: A way of doing this problem is to use the work-energy theorem, work done = change in kinetic energy which immediately shows that no work was done in intervals $A, \, C$ and $D$ and positive work was done in interval $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, and the answer in blue ink is wrong.  Between 15 and 17.5 seconds, there is a force opposing the motion, and the work done by the external force is negative.  That force is maintained from 17.5 to 20 seconds, but now is in the same direction as the motion, so work is positive.  The total work between 15 and 20 seconds is zero, which makes sense, as the box has the same amount of kinetic energy at the beginning and end of the interval.

Comment: The answer in blue also seems to imply that the work done during B is negative, which it is not: the force is in the same direction as the displacement, and the kinetic energy of the box increases.  Work done is positive.